# sed - only get single occurrence

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am using the below SED command:

```
sed '/cell.* '"alatch {"'/,/^}/p' -n file
```

Input file is as under:

```
cell abc { 
    pins on T {
        a b c
    }
    
}
cell xyz { 
    pins on T {
        x y z
    }
    
}

cell alatch { 
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
cell alatch { 
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
```

Output is as under:

```
cell alatch { 
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
cell alatch { 
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
```

Expected out is as under:

```
cell alatch { 
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
```

What is needed is that only the first occurrence should be the output. Any suggestion for command?

Comment: Clarify the exact occurrence of *what* you want. Also, I don't think your quoting, while probably not incorrect, makes much sense and only obfuscates the `sed` command. How about `'/cell.* alatch {/,/^}/p'` as a start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the *first* of the two identical blocks:

```
$ sed '/cell alatch {/,/^}/!d; /^}/q' file
cell alatch {
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
```

The `/cell alatch {/,/^}/` range is the range of lines that you want to get as output.

The `sed` expressions first deletes all lines *not* in this range, and then *quits* as soon as a `}` is found at the start of a line.  The `q` instruction will cause `sed` to terminate after it outputs the current line, so the final `}` will get printed.

Executing the `d` instruction *immediately* skips to the next input line and branches back to the start of the editing script, so the `q` instruction has no way of executing unless it's in the range which does not cause `d` to execute.

---

With `awk`, achieving the same effect with code that should be reminiscent of the `sed` code above:

```
$ awk '/cell alatch {/,/^}/ { print; if ($0 ~ /^}/) exit }' file
cell alatch {
    pins on T {
        VSS VDDPI VDDP
    }
    pins on L {
        IN CT CB
    }
    pins on R {
        OUT
    }
    inputs {
        CB CT IN
    }
    outputs {
        OUT
    }
}
```

Actually, this is closer to the `sed` command

```
sed -n '/cell alatch {/,/^}/{ p; /^}/q; }' file
```

which does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

With **awk** we accumulate the desired cell data and when the depth (number of { = number of } reaches 0 we dump the cell data nd quit.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { ORS = "" }
  /cell alatch \{/ {inCell=1}
  !inCell {next}
  {data = data $0 RS} 
  /\}/ {depth--} 
  /\{/ {depth++}
  !depth {
    print data 
    exit
  }
' ./file
```

---

Using **GNU sed**  with the same idea of the awk code above.

```
sed -e '
  /cell alatch {/!d
  /\n/!{h;s/.*/x/;x;}
  $d;N
  /}$/{x;s/x//;/x/!{x;q;};x;}
  /{$/{x;s/$/x/;x;}
  s/^/\n/;D
' file
```